# Finding vectors in a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am in linear algebra and was given this question as a review:

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  be the set of all vectors $(x, y, z)$ such that $x + 2y + 3z = 0$.

Find two vectors $v, w \in E$ such that
$E = \{av + bw | a, b \in \mathbb R\}$.

I was thinking about turning this into a matrix to solve for each variable but each one only has one coefficient. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Your equation defines a plane.  Find the normal vector ${\bf n}$ to that plane.  Then find any two distinct vectors ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf w}$ perpendicular to ${\bf n}$.

Comment: Yes, and in order to find $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$, you can take simple unit vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and apply Gramm-Schmidt orthogonalization with respect to initially found $\textbf{n}$.

Comment: Or just find a basis for the kernel of the matrix $A=(1 2 3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is the set
$$ \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid (1,2,3) \cdot (x,y,z) = 0 \},$$
which is a plane with normal vector $n = (1,2,3)$.

Next find a vector $v$ satisfying $n\cdot v = 0$.
A third vector in $E$ that is not a multiple of $v$ can be found by taking the cross product of $n$ and $v$.